# Inno User Input Passed To URL

Tags: inno-setup

I am trying to find a way to get two pieces of information and pass them to a php page during the installation.  I have a VBS file that can call the URL, but don't know how to pass the user input to the URL.

Comment: can you paste the code in question?

Answer (score 3):

You can create a custom page using `CreateCustomPage()` or one of the `CreateInput*Page()` functions.

You can then make the HTTP request using one of the [ISXDL](http://www.dateiliste.com/d3files/tools/mphider/isxdl.htm) and [InnoTools Downloader](http://sherlocksoftware.org/page.php?id=50) libraries allow an Inno setup to make HTTP requests.